# Why do I get "Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag"?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I am trying to suggest that [tez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tez) should be a synonym of [apache-tez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tez). How to do this?

Here is what I am trying:

[image]

I wonder why..

Comment: Talk to these 4 guys: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2256902/manjunath-ballur, http://stackoverflow.com/users/2328389/sonofsun, http://stackoverflow.com/users/779290/po-zhou, and http://stackoverflow.com/users/2414957/mona-jalal. The four of them have the required tag score, you would need just 1 more.

Comment: You probably mean to chat with them, since the 1st I checked doesn't have contact info, something I have only being doing via the Let us continue... option in the comments section @Braiam, thank you though!

Comment: You can leave a random comment on one of his posts too.

Comment: I can @Braiam, but I'd rather not, it [would remind me of this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes/2789967?noredirect=1#comment66122915_2789967). :)

Comment: But @Braiam, wait a minute! I used [tag:apache-tez] in [Is Hive faster than Spark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416007/is-hive-faster-than-spark) Does that mean that if I get an upvote there, I will then be able to be the 5h guy? Because if so, then it would make sense to struggle in contacting the other 4.

Comment: Only if you get score 5 on that single question.

Comment: The question has 0 at the moment @Braiam, not so good! :)

Comment: "I wonder why.." Maybe because you cannot be trusted without that score?

Comment: FWIW @Braiam even if OP had gotten a score of 5 on the question, they still couldn't do the synonym action. Tag score only comes from answer votes (which you probably have discovered since 2016...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can't. The error message is fairly clear about the *what*: you can't propose a tag synonym because you don't have a score of 5 or greater in that tag.

What is lacking is the explanation of *why*, but I can tell you that: because [the tag synonym system is completely and utterly broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work), and [nobody wants to do anything about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag). Which forces everyone to come to Meta and ask for tag synonyms to be created, or worse, to "burninate" the tags that should be synonymized because burninate just sounds so much cooler and they've seen lots of "burnination" requests with clever puns in the title.

Comment: Right... Should I edit my question to ask for the synonym or post a new question?

Comment: Up to you. [A guy in a non-black suit just asked for the same thing with another tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334231/will-a-mod-please-synonymize-smartmatch-and-smart-matching). Empirically speaking, synonym requests don't get much traction because they require a moderator's intervention, and I guess moderators are reluctant to step in and do something that cannot be easily reversed without clear community consensus. If only there was a way that we could, you know, have the community *vote* on tag synonyms...