# Will a mod please synonymize smartmatch and smart-matching?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

[smartmatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartmatch) and [smart-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smart-matching) describe the exact same feature in Perl. The [official name of the operator is "smartmatch,"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) so [smart-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smart-matching) should be made a synonym of [smartmatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartmatch).

There are [only four users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/536899/users-with-5-in-smartmatch-tag) with +5 in [smartmatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartmatch), so this can't be done without a mod (or some strategic re-tagging and [a lot of waiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work)).

Will a mod please make the synonym?

Comment: +1 for asking a synonym, rather a burnitation (damn, how is this thing spelled).

Comment: Wouldn't manual retagging be faster?

Comment: @Braiam It sure would. If that's all it takes, what's the point of synonyms on low-traffic tags?

Comment: Not sure, I'm just telling you the most cost-efficient way.

Comment: @Braiam It honestly didn't even occur to me to just re-tag them manually. I wish I'd thought of that before stalking mods in chat and posting here. There's 12 minutes of my life that I'll never get back :(

Comment: I'm marking this [status-declined] now, as there is no use of adding a synonym at the moment (one of the tags is dead). But henceforth, please do not go to retag the questions manually. Mods have a very easy way to do this, in a click of a few buttons. It is not at all a problem for us. Posting a synonym request is all the work that you need to do, from now on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never mind. As Braiam suggested, I re-tagged these myself (there were only 17 [smart-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smart-matching) questions). There's so little traffic in these tags that we probably don't need a synonym.

While I was at it, I also submitted an edit to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13763055) (which had some woefully out-of-date information) and the [wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13763056) (which was a bit vague). I submitted both changes at once, so my edit comment doesn't make a lot of sense if you only see the excerpt; if people could check my edits before the robo-reviewers get to them, I would appreciate it.